# Individual Spark Task consume more time on computation if more cores are assigned

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark job with input file of size 6.6G (hdfs) with master as local. My Spark Job with 53 partitions completed quickly when I assign local[6] than local[2], however the individual task takes more computation time when number of cores are more. Say if I assign 1 core(local[1]) then each task takes 3 secs where the same goes up to 12 seconds if I assign 6 cores (local[6]). Where the time gets wasted? The spark UI shows increase in computation time for each task in local[6] case, I couldn't understand the reason why the same code takes different computation time when more cores are assigned.

**Update:**

I could see more %iowait in iostat output if I use local[6] than local[1]. Please let me know this is the only reason or any possible reasons. I wonder why this iowait is not reported in sparkUI. I see the increase in computing time than iowait time.

Comment: How many cores do you actually have available on your machine?

Comment: The system has 8 cores.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to `spark.task.cpus` and not `spark.cores.max`

With `spark.tasks.cpus` each task get assigned more cores, but it doesn't necessarily have to use them. If you process is single threaded it really can't use them. You wind up with additional overhead without additional benefit and those cores are taken away from other single threaded tasks that can use them.

With `spark.cores.max` it is simply and overhead issue with transferring data around at the same time.

Comment: I am using spark-submit with --master local[6]/local[1]. Per spark doc _local[K] Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine)._